# How to set exact margins in KOMA-Script Report

Tags: margins, koma-script, geometry, scrreprt

I am creating a document using the KOMA-Script class `scrreprt`. It is to be handed in and the requirements specify the following page layout:

1. A4 paper
2. One-sided print
3. Margins: left 3.5 cm (2.5cm margin + 1cm binding), right 2.5, top 2.5, bottom 2.5

When I try using the `geometry` package, it sort of screws it up - just by measuring with a ruler, I see that it's not correct. Using `showframe`, I can also see that there is a lot of space below the text area, presumably footer and such in addition to the margin, that I don't need.

The KOMA-Script documentation states (and, for the record, I agree that this is the better way) that the page layout should be set using `typearea` with `DIV` and `BCOR` values, but I don't know how to translate the specs into them.

How can I set 1.--3. in `scrreprt`?

UPDATE: This may, indeed, be caused by the printer. Thanks for the comments, I am now looking into it!

UPDATE 2: The issue I was grappling with was, indeed, caused by the printer. However, the answers given are very appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure your printer driver isn't using "Shrink to printable area"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You gave no MWE so I have to guess a little bit :-(

It is not a good idea to mix KOMA-Script mechanismn with the usage of `geometry`.

In your case the big problem is that KOMA-Script always uses with its own calculated typing area an bottom line which is double top line!

You want both lines to be equal: `top 2.5, bottom 2.5`.

So get your three points use the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
  \pagestyle{scrheadings}
  \cfoot{\pagemark}
  \ofoot{yyyy-mm-dd}
  \ifoot{Author X}

\usepackage[%
  paper=a4paper,
  left=25mm,
  right=25mm,
  top=25mm,
  bottom=25mm,
  bindingoffset=10mm,
  includefoot,
  foot=\baselineskip,
  showframe
]{geometry}
%\recalctypearea % for testing: using KOMA-Script type area calculating too


\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

And gives you:

[image]

To test the missmatch by mixing `geometry` and KOMA-Script mechanismn uncoment the line

```
%\recalctypearea % for testing: using KOMA-Script type area calculating too
```

and compile again. The wrong result you now get is:

[image]

As you can see the bottom line is double top line and binding correction is missing ...

Answer (score 3):

A4 paper (`paper=a4`) and one-sided print (`twoside=false`) are defaults for the `scrreprt` class.

For the special margins package `geometry` is recommended. To avoid the change by an explicit or implicit recalculation by KOMA-Script you can use `\AfterCalculatingTypearea`.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\chead*{\pagemark}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\AfterCalculatingTypearea{\geometry{margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=1cm,nofoot}}
\recalctypearea

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]